# How significant is signal noise from a BNC connector?

Tags: signal

I'm trying to build a double cross antenna that can be folded/taken apart based on the design of the picture and receive signals from weather satellites. The idea is to make each of the four dipoles detachable but I'm not sure what the best way of connecting the dipoles is. The signals of the four dipoles are wired together later on.

I don't know that much about antennas but my idea was to have a BNC connector at each dipole. So my question is this: **How significant can I expect the noise to be compared to soldering the BNC cable directly to the poles and are there any better methods I am missing?**

[image: Antenna Reference]

Answer (score 1):

Compared to a BNC, good RF connector will do a better job at matching impedances, and providing the lowest SWR possible, and the highest efficiency transmission, for a well-designed system.

Generally, a BNC connector might be used in a situation where a 50 Ohm match, less than 80 W, less than 500 MHz.

For most amateur operations consider your power, band, and how stable you need the connection to be. I'd generally use a threaded connector, SMA type or N-type. You see less degradation of cable performance over time and a more stable connection.

In all cases, corrosion, moisture, dirt, and contamination can be a source of stay currents, triboelectric, or other contact noise which can grow to significant levels.

https://www.arworld.us/resources/Guide-to-RF-Coaxial-Connectors-and-Cables.asp

Comment: Yup, BNC is not a good choice for outside environments. They will work for a while but there's no direct weather seal.